# Loading column block style seperately

Tags: block-editor, wp-register-style

I am building a hybrid theme and don't want to use the full block styles. So I enabled should_load_separate_core_block_assets. Now I want to register some basic styles for the whole site and some block styles conditionally.

How can I, for example register the column block styles only?